# Outputting to csv without stop words

Tags: python, csv

So I have this code here that searches through a csv file called, "claims" to see if it contains any of the words found in the csv file "sexualHarassment" and it prints those results into a new csv file. This part works great.

The part I'm having trouble with is removing the stop words. I have a third csv file that contains one column of stop words. I can't figure out how to have these outputted without the stop words. Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
    import csv

    with open("claims.csv") as file1, open("sexualHarassment.csv") as file2,
    open("stopwords.csv") as file3, open("output.csv", "wb+") as file4:
        writer = csv.writer(file4)
        key_words = [word.strip() for word in file2.readlines()]
        stop_words = [stop.strip() for stop in file3.readlines()]
        for row in file1:
            row = row.strip()
            for key in key_words:
                if key in row:
                   writer.writerow([key, row])
```

Comment: To answer the question in your title: yes, you can. Not sure how it relates to the body of your post, though.

Comment: I had a different question in mind at first, apologies

Comment: Are you trying to remove the stop words from each row, or not print the row at all?

Comment: I'm trying to remove each stop word from every row and print the rows without stop words. @TheSoundDefense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

As to the question body. You can remove all keywords from the row using the [replace](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm) function:

```
for key in keywords: 
    row = row.replace(key, "")
```

EDIT:

```
for key in stopwords: 
    row = row.replace(key, "")
```

EDIT END

I don't know if it is your intention, but unless you want to possibly add the same row repeatedly (if multiple keywords exist per line) you might want to do something like

```
        for key in key_words:
            if key in row:
               writer.writerow([key, row])
               break # would not recommend using breaks but that's more personal taste
```

or

```
        flag = False;
        for key in key_words:
            if key in row:
               flag = True;
        if flag:
            writer.writerow([key, row])
```

LG

Comment: Thank you, this actually helped me remove the duplicates (which I was going to do after) But in reference to the first part of your answer, I'm not trying to remove keywords, I'm trying to remove stopwords

Comment: Sry, just replace keywords with stopwords

Comment: I'm sorry, where in my code do I place this? Because I've been playing around with it, and every time the csv ends up outputting blank @Daniel Kogan

Comment: I figured it out @Daniel Kogan! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove a list of words from a longer string, you can use the `replace` function, like so:

```
row = "stop go stop stop2 yellow stop3 hi"
stop_list = ["stop","stop2","stop3"]     # You'd get this from the file.
for stop_word in stop_list:
  row = row.replace(stop_word,"")
print row                                 # Output: " go   yellow  hi"
```

This basically iterates over every stop word and replaces it with `""` in your row, effectively removing them.

Don't ask where I came up with the example words because I don't know.